# Custom Argument for a build definition

Tags: xaml, workflow, build-process

Is it possible to modify the xaml for a build definition's workflow to have a custom argument that is not dependent on a custom assembly. [This tutorial](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/17/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-6-Use-custom-type-for-an-argument.aspx) shows how to create a custom argument but its in an the given assembly. I have build definitions that are shared and don't want to have the baggage of an assembly.

So basically I just want a custom argument in which I can supply some options for in the xaml and then when configuring the build definition in the ui you would be pressented with a drop box of these defined options.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: If I understand it right, you just want a variable to be passed as an input into xaml right?  And you don't want to have a library for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add a "enum" style value to the TFS Build Parameters then you will need a Custom Assembly. The tutorial you have linked to covers the process for setting up TFS and adding a custom assembly.

Once you have this you should check in the binary for the Custom Assembly to source control. For example: `$/MyProject/CustomAssemblies/`. From Team Explorer (VS2012+) you can got Builds then Actions and select "Manage Build Controllers", select your controller from there and click Properties. Here you can enter the same path you checked in your custom assembly. Now any builds done by this controller will know where to find your assembly.

Comment: Right but how do I added a  collection of static values for the given argument. I want to add a handful of static values that can be chosen from...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question fully. You cannot do this without a custom assembly. However you can configure a "build controller" to use a single custom assembly location for all builds it performs.

Comment: Do you have any info on configuration for the build server, I would like to try that then.

Comment: @Gabe - I've re-written my answer.

Comment: Sorry @Gabe I had that link open, but I forgot to paste it into the answer.

Comment: @DaveShaw... so I have my custom assembly in source control and have set the path $\MyProjects\foo\bar to the binary. It does exist in TFS. Whenever I load my template I get an error, "No assemblies were found in the custom assembly path. The assemblies may not exist or you may not have permissions to read them. Contact your Team Foundation Administrator for more information." If I place the assembly in my local GAC the template works. Any idea what I missed in configuration of the custom assembly path in TFS?

Comment: Have a look in your output Window for under the "Team Foundation" section, I think that's everything.

Comment: Yea that's the error i see in the output for Team Foundation.  "No assemblies were found in the custom assembly path. The assemblies may not exist or you may not have permissions to read them. Contact your Team Foundation Administrator for more information.